# What is grid decomposition?

Tags: dataset

I'm reading a [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6121313&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6121313) about DBSCAN implementation on Map-Reduce. In preprocessing step, it wants to divide dataset and it says:

> We consider two strategies in this paper for different scenarios. The ﬁrst one is given the number of computing slots N and its grid decomposition (N = a ∗ b), it could ﬁnd an
>   approximate division in raw spatial data.

I don't get it exactly. Does he want to get coefficients of number of processing unit and use them to divide different dimensions of data?

**P.S:** Please help me choose appropriate tags.

Comment: Can you link the paper or give us the citation?

Comment: @DavidMarx I linked it.

Comment: It looks like a parallel computing text. ["Grid decomposition is a major issue in parallel programming."](http://www.cas.usf.edu/~cconnor/parallel/grid-decomp1/grid1.html)